# Sub-domain on a dedicated server

Tags: dns, hosting, subdomain

I don't know if my title made any since because I'm not sure what the terminology for what I'm trying to do is.  Let me just explain my situation and see if anyone can shed light on to what to do next.

So I'm working on a research grant and we've got a shared server with GoDaddy currently serving our domain(also managed by GoDaddy).   We also have a dedicated server through GoDaddy that we are using to do heavy computations on the research side of things.  What I need to do is tie a sub-domain (say research.ourdomain.org) to the dedicated server.  I tried sub domain-forwarding and Masking (forwarded to a Silverlight app) and this works until someone tries to request a page outside of our Silverlight app(at which point it first hits the Silverlight app then goes to a blank page).  I feel like I'm going in the wrong direction with sub-domain forwarding and masking.  Is their a better way to achieve what I need?

I hope that question wasn't too convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without forwarding and masking. All you need to do is setup the server to host the subdomain. Then you will need to create the A record in your DNS control and point it to your server IP. The link, http://x.co/ZmgJ, will have more info on how to create that record. If you need server assistance, http://x.co/ZmgM can show you how to initiate live chat with our server conceirges.